# SQL get monthly/weekly data sum?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, group-by

I get Daily sum of data with these lines?

```
SELECT convert(varchar, okuma_tarihi, 102) as Gunler,SUM(toplam_kullanim_T1) as TotalUsageValue,'T1' as UsageType FROM TblSayacOkumalari
GROUP BY convert(varchar, okuma_tarihi, 102)
UNION ALL
SELECT convert(varchar, okuma_tarihi, 102) as Gunler,SUM(toplam_kullanim_T2) as TotalUsageValue,'T2' as UsageType FROM TblSayacOkumalari 
GROUP BY convert(varchar, okuma_tarihi, 102)
UNION ALL
SELECT convert(varchar, okuma_tarihi, 102) as Gunler,SUM(toplam_kullanim_T3) as TotalUsageValue,'T3' as UsageType FROM TblSayacOkumalari
GROUP BY convert(varchar, okuma_tarihi, 102)
```

How Can I get SUM of data weekly or mounthly? Is there any turorial about this topic or code example? When I write `MONTH(DATE)` instead of `convert(varchar, okuma_tarihi, 102)` It shows , for example all sum of data in that month. (2010 june value + 2011 june value). I dont want this. I use MSSQL Server 2008.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
GROUP BY YEAR(<date_column_name>),MONTH(<date_column_name>) --for months
```

Or

```
GROUP BY YEAR(<date_column_name>),DATEPART(wk,<date_column_name>) --for weeks
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using 3 different statement and then union all. These can be done in single statement as your grouping column is date and is same.However, only proble with that would be that you will get one row with all 3 sum as columns instead of 3 rows.But you can use unpivot to make columns to rows. That will be much more effective as you will doing the work just once rather than 3 times.On a big table it could be big performance improvement.

Regarding sum by year and month it has been answered only